# Workaround jarring menu-in-toolbar style in WPF

Tags: wpf, menu, styles, toolbar

I've troubles getting to play a `<Menu/>` within a `<Toolbar/>` to play nice. My Example, as follows is placed in an empty window in a default WpfApplication project template from VS2010:

```
<DockPanel>
    <ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Button Content="Button 1"/>
        <Button Content="Button 2"/>
        <Separator/>
        <CheckBox Content="CheckBox 1"/>
        <CheckBox Content="CheckBox 2"/>
        <Separator/>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="Menu">
                <MenuItem Header="File">
                    <MenuItem Header="Copy"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Paste"/>
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </ToolBar>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="Menu">
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="Copy"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Paste"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

The default style mis-aligns both the label and the hover-indicator:

[image: menu-in-toolbar styling fail]

I'm no designer, nor a WPF-guru, so my simple attempts at getting the menu's style closer to the buttons have failed catastrophically.

Has anybody a simple (ideally based on `Toolbar.MenuStyleKey`) Style to get the Menu back in line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick thing that seemed to work in KaXaml:

```
    <ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Button Content="Button 1"/>
        <Button Content="Button 2"/>
        <Separator/>
        <CheckBox Content="CheckBox 1"/>
        <CheckBox Content="CheckBox 2"/>
        <Separator/>
        <Menu Margin="0, -1, 0, 0" Style="{x:Null}">
            <MenuItem Header="Menu">
                <MenuItem Header="File">
                    <MenuItem Header="Copy"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Paste"/>
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </ToolBar>
```

Comment: P.S: This approach doesn't work when the Menu is applied as DataTemplate. I've now set a different margin and a transparent background which is still not perfect, but still looks better than the default.